# What is the fourth parameter in mysqli_connect()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is "forks" in mySQL

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("db location","username","password", "forks") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: @Warren Sergent - spakatak.com : Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its database name

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

---

```
Parameter      Description
host           Optional. Specifies a host name or an IP address
username       Optional. Specifies the MySQL username
password       Optional. Specifies the MySQL password
dbname         Optional. Specifies the default database to be used
port           Optional. Specifies the port number to attempt to connect to the MySQL server
socket         Optional. Specifies the socket or named pipe to be used
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `forks` is the fourth parameter, so it is simply the name of the database. The word `forks` is otherwise meaningless in MySQL, and doesn't bear any relevance to the code itself.

The parameters of the `mysqli_connect()` PHP function are as follows:

1. Host
2. Username
3. Password
4. Database Name
5. Port
6. Socket

See the PHP Manual for the [mysqli::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) function, of which [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is an alias.